# Как в Maven собрать проект с компоновкой готовой либы и ее измененных классов?

Tags: java, maven

Есть проект в Maven на Java. В зависимостях проекта есть библиотека, в исходниках проекта я меняю некоторые классы этой библиотеки. В итоге мне нужно собрать новую версию этой библиотеки, где измененные класса должны заменить старые, а не измененные просто скопироваться. Знаю как это провернуть в Gradle, а тут не получается.

Comment: По сути, вам нужно собрать свою версию библиотеки, а потом подключить её к проекту, как обычную зависимость. Какая часть этого процесса вызывает сложности?

Comment: Как мне заставить аттачиться классы из библиотеки, которая в зависимостях в собираемый пакет? Я имею ввиду как настроить конфигурационный файл. Собрать новые классы я могу без проблем, но приходится кидать их в jar библиотеки, заменяя старые. А хочется, чтобы при mvn package, собирался jar автоматически со всеми изменениями, то есть старые классы (нетронутые) + измененные классы.

Comment: Как-то Вы чересчур усложняете процесс. Давайте разберемся сначала, чем являются эти "измененные классы". Имеют ли они отношение к вашему проекту (и зависимость от него)? Если да, то зачем их пытаться затолкать обратно в библиотеку? Лучше импортировать библиотеку как есть, а новые классы оставить непосредственно в проекте, затолкав в отдельный package с гордым именем utils, к примеру. Если нет, то нужно, по сути, сделать свою библиотеку на основе существующей, запустить для удобства какой-нибудь Nexus или Archiva и выложить туда этот артефакт, откуда его и импортировать.

Comment: Ок, я понял, спасибо.